# Javascript - Change page style without showing previous one

Tags: javascript, css

I have a website that I want to add different styles to. The user may choose any style he wants, I store it in localStorage and display it. I have this code:

`<link href="default.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" onload="this.href = window.localStorage['webpage_style'];"/>`

This works OK, but I have a problem with buttons. The `default.css` is white style - just like here on stack overflow. But the new one is dark style, with dark gray background and so on. My problem with the button is: on every page load with that new dark style, the button is white and then changes to dark rapidly, but the white moment is clearly visible and it looks awful. What can I do to stop the effect on page load?

Here are both CSS:

```css
button {
  width: 88%;
  padding: 1.5em;
  background-color: white;
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin: 1.8%;
  margin-bottom: 0.2%;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: background-color 0.3s ease-in-out;
}

button:hover {
  background-color: #e8e8e8;
}

button:focus {
  outline: none;
}
```

```html
<button>Sample - Default CSS</button>
```

```css
button {
  width: 88%;
  padding: 1.5em;
  background-color: white;
  border: 1px solid #c8c8c8;
  /* Change here */
  margin: 1.8%;
  margin-bottom: 0.2%;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: background-color 0.3s ease-in-out;
  background-color: #272323;
  /* Change here */
  color: #c8c8c8;
  /* Change here */
}

button:hover {
  background-color: #3b3636;
  /* Change here */
}

button:focus {
  outline: none;
}
```

```html
<button>Sample - Dark CSS</button>
```

What can I do to not show that effect? The button turns from white to black in like 0.3s. Is there any way to do it? Or should I just remove the transition line in CSS (that stops the effect, but is there any other way)?

Comment: The only way to prevent the issue is to load that appropriate CSS file and block the UI while that happens, which really is not a good idea.

Comment: So I should remove the transition?

Comment: What are you using the transition for? Is it necessary?

Comment: The transition isn't part of the problem. The problem is the latency in loading the alternate stylesheet.

Comment: Can I somehow display the site content after the alternate stylesheet is loaded? Something like onbeforeload event, IDK. I've tried to insert <script> tag in head with code, but it didn't worked

Comment: You can hide use body { display: none; } in the old css and body { display: block; } in the loaded css to show content after css has loaded.

Answer (score 0):

You're telling the browser to wait for the [load-event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onload), this (from the aforementioned MDN-docs):

> ...fires at the end of the document loading process. At this point, all of the objects in the document are in the DOM, and all the images, scripts, links and sub-frames have finished loading.

Hence, don't use `onload` if you don't need to wait for the DOM to be ready.

```
<link href="default.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" id="dynamic_stylesheet" />
<script>
if (window.localStorage['webpage_style']) {
  var styleLink = document.getElementById("dynamic_stylesheet");
  styleLink.href = window.localStorage['webpage_style'];
}
</script>
```

Or if that still introduces a flash you could write the style link conditionally in JS.

```
<script>
    if (window.localStorage['webpage_style']) {
        document.write("<link href=\""+window.localStorage['webpage_style']+"\" type=\"text/css\" rel=\"stylesheet\" />");
    } else {
        document.write("<link href=\"default.css\" type=\"text/css\" rel=\"stylesheet\" />");
    }
</script>
<noscript>
    <link href="default.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
</noscript>
```